# @ApplicationScoped doesn't have the expected effect

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish

I am making my first steps with J2EE and Glassfish. I am experimenting with [the examples from the J2EE 6 tutorial](https://java.net/downloads/javaeetutorial/javaeetutorial6.zip), more specifically "hello1".

I have the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Hello {
    private String name;
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Hello.class.getName()); 

    public Hello() {
        log.info("Ctor: Hello has been created" + this.getClass().getName()); 
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        log.info("postConstruct() " + this.getClass().getName()); 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String user_name) {
        this.name = user_name;
    }
}
```

And the following XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelets Hello Greeting</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:graphicImage url="duke.waving.gif"/>
            <h2>Hello, my name is Duke. What's yours?</h2>
            <h:inputText id="username" 
                         value="#{hello.name}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="A name is required."
                         maxlength="25">
            </h:inputText>
            <p></p>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response">
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The application is working, but obviously multiple instances of the bean are created:

```
2014-03-27T11:23:44.077+0100|Information: Ctor: Hello has been createdhello1.Hello
2014-03-27T11:23:44.077+0100|Information: postConstruct() hello1.Hello
2014-03-27T11:23:46.713+0100|Information: Ctor: Hello has been createdhello1.Hello
2014-03-27T11:23:46.713+0100|Information: postConstruct() hello1.Hello
2014-03-27T11:23:49.112+0100|Information: Ctor: Hello has been createdhello1.Hello
2014-03-27T11:23:49.112+0100|Information: postConstruct() hello1.Hello
```

At first I thought that proxy were created, that's why I added `this.getClass().getName()` in the log, but it doesn't to be the case. Furthermore, the hello.name is not shared among instances.

From all the documentation and examples I could read, `@ApplicationScoped` should create a singleton at application level. Also, `eager=trye` doesn't work as expected, since no instance is created at application startup. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: are you sure you are importing the right ApplicationScoped class ?

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

One minute after having sent the question, I found out the problem. As suspected by Adarsh, I was importing `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` instead of `javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped`

Comment: An interesting reading on this issue: http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html